# some oaths vs oaths

Tags: usage

Is there any difference (in nuances, or commonness, ...) between the following sentences?

> When John is angry, he lets out *some oaths*.
>
> When John is angry, he lets out *oaths*.
>
> When John is angry, he lets out *oath*.

Is there any general rule regarding the difference between *Xs* and *some Xs*? I've already seen [coffee vs. some coffee](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250715/coffee-vs-some-coffee)
, but it seems to me to be about the particular case in which X=coffee.

Comment: None of them is particularly idiomatic.  When John is angry he curses (or cusses).

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks. Do you mean "letting an oath" is not idiomatic at all? Or it  used in some other situations?

Comment: It's not idiomatic in the US.

Comment: In everyday speech, it would be more usual to say 'he curses' or 'he swears'.  In a work of fiction, describing a single incident 'John let out _an_ oath' (or 'a string of oaths') would be acceptable. In your examples, 'oaths' (bad words in general) is better than 'some oaths', which implies that John only uses a few of the words that he might choose. (Of course he may have a few favourite swear words, but the sentence still looks odd.)

Comment: "Oath" is almost archaic, and "lets out" would not be used with it today. In any case you would never use "some" in this context. This is a question for English Language Learners.

Comment: @David According to the [Ngram of let out oaths, let out some oaths, let out an oath, and curses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let+out+oaths%2Clet+out+some+oaths%2Clet+out+an+oath%2C+curses&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20out%20an%20oath%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurses%3B%2Cc0) the first two phrases have no ngram and the third is far less frequent than the fourth. So I agree that, compared with _curses_, _oath_ is almost archaic, but why do you assert that _some_ is never used in this context, as _oaths_ is also never used?

Answer (score 1):

"When John is angry, he lets out some oaths."

Each time John is angry, he lets out/utters a number of oaths greater than one (this is indicated by the plural 'oaths').

> some determiner (UNKNOWN AMOUNT) ​ an amount or number of something
>   that is not stated or not known [Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/some)

"When John is angry, he lets out oaths."

Each time  John is angry, he habitually lets out one or more oaths. The absence of the determiner'some' means that the number of oaths, while still unknown, could be one.

"When John is angry, he lets out oath."

Not proper English. Either an oath or oaths (plural) or some oaths.

Answer (score 0):

According to "Практическая грамматика английского языка" by Качалова, there is. 
For example, if an Englishman says:
- "He has sent me some magazines from Leningrad" - he means that he received a certain AMOUNT of magazines. But, when he says:
- "He has sent me magazines from Leningrad" - he means that he received **magazines**, and not bears or balalaikas.

Comment: In the case it's available online, would you please provide a link to the source you mentioned.

Comment: It is a very popular book in Russia. You just have to google "Качалова, Израилевич, Английский" and you get about a hundred links to download. You might try http://nashol.com/2014070678736/prakticheskaya-grammatika-angliiskogo-yazika-tom-2-kachalova-k-n-izrailevich-e-e-2003.html

Comment: You can only talk about amount of magazines if you are weighing them. Like a certain Russian politician, things that are popular in Russia don't necessarily go down well here.

Comment: I'm a little curious as to why you think this is at all relevant to the question.